# Is sending requests to a server (which uses a model trained by GPL-licensed software) distribution according to the GPL?

Tags: gpl, distribution

I have a software in which I use Weka software to train a model (classifier) just once (without any modification) and save the model somewhere. Then, our customer gives a document to the program and gets the result back based on evaluating the saved model on the given document.

What our customer does is just sending a request to the server through the website and getting the results back. Does it mean that we are distributing the code according to GPL?

If I don't want to make our code under GPL license, can't I use Weka?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running GPL-licensed programs and in particular here calling a GPL-licensed through a network interface (a website) would not be considered redistribution under the GPL (it may in some cases under the AGPL but not under the GPL).

As long as you do not redistribute your code and the Weka code that evaluates a doc on a saved model, you are not redistributing but only merely using and running the code.